# understanding "ip addr change" and "ip addr replace" commands

Tags: linux, ip

At the moment I have following IPv4 addresses associated with *eth0* interface:

```
T60:~ # ip -V
ip utility, iproute2-ss110629
T60:~ # ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:58:2a:84:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.11.12.2/24 scope global eth0
    inet 10.11.12.3/24 scope global secondary eth0
    inet 10.11.12.4/24 scope global secondary eth0
    inet6 fe80::215:58ff:fe2a:843e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
T60:~ #
```

I would like to replace or change 10.11.12.3/24 address to 10.11.12.6/24. How to do this? If I execute `ip addr change 10.11.12.6/24 dev eth0` or `ip addr replace 10.11.12.6/24 dev eth0` then 10.11.12.6 is just added to eth0. In addition, in case of change/replace, shouldn't the syntax be `change/replace from 10.11.12.3/24 to 10.11.12.6/24`? I know that I can use `ip addr del` command, but how to achieve this with `ip addr change` or `ip addr replace`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

(I realize this is an old question, but Google brought me here because I was trying to figure out exactly what `change` and `replace` do and how they are different).

I believe that both `replace` and `change` are used for modifying an existing address.  Consider:

```bash
ip addr add 192.168.111.10/32 dev dummy0
```

This gets me:

```
32: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 5a:ec:58:4f:d1:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.111.10/32 scope global dummy0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::58ec:58ff:fe4f:d135/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I run the same command again, I get an error:

```
# ip addr add 192.168.111.10/32 dev dummy0 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

If I want to modify the flags on that address, I can use either `change` or `replace`.  Here, I use `ip addr change` to modify the `preferred_lft` and `valid_lft` settings on that address:

```
# ip addr change 192.168.111.10/32 dev dummy0  preferred_lft 300 valid_lft 300
# ip addr show dummy0
32: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 5a:ec:58:4f:d1:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.111.10/32 scope global dynamic dummy0
       valid_lft 298sec preferred_lft 298sec
    inet6 fe80::58ec:58ff:fe4f:d135/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The behavior of `ip addr replace` is identical.  In fact, if you look at the code, they result in almost identical actions:

```
    if (matches(*argv, "change") == 0 ||
            strcmp(*argv, "chg") == 0)
            return ipaddr_modify(RTM_NEWADDR, NLM_F_REPLACE, argc-1, argv+1);
    if (matches(*argv, "replace") == 0)
            return ipaddr_modify(RTM_NEWADDR, NLM_F_CREATE|NLM_F_REPLACE, argc-1, argv+1);
```

It looks like the intention here is that `change` will only modify an existing address, while `replace` will either modify an existing address or create a new one if the specified address does not exist.  In practice, it seems as if both `change` and `replace` will add the address if it does not already exist.

If you actually want to add a new address and remove an old one, you will need to do that in two steps, using `ip addr del` followed by `ip addr add` (or the other way around, of course).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It saved my production environment a ton of downtime (if only I had found it earlier, I could've had `NO` `P0`s :( )

Comment: Fyi, `NLM_F_CREATE` and `NLM_F_REPLACE` are described on [this page](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/route.html).  I don't know what any of the description means (because I don't know what a "qdisc" is), but here it is:  `NLM_F_CREATE`
Create qdisc if it does not exist, otherwise `-NLE_OBJ_NOTFOUND` is returned. 
 `NLM_F_REPLACE` If another qdisc is already attached to the same parent and their handles mismatch, replace the qdisc instead of returning `-EEXIST.`  `NLM_F_EXCL`
Return `-NLE_EXISTS` if a qdisc with matching handles exists already.